# How can I make my custom dependency properties sorted to the top when called in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I am creating a custom control and I have created several dependency properties. I want to know how can I have my custom dependency properties show up on top with a star such as the picture below.

[image]

Comment: It is automatically determined by IntelliCode. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/overview#context-aware-code-completions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control this explicitly. The "IntelliCode" feature uses a form of machine learning to create models that are used by the editor to present this list and to decide which members show up at the top of the list with a star.

However, you can attempt to train a model specific to your code base. See [IntelliCode team completions: AI-assisted IntelliSense based on your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/custom-models) for details about that. Note that since one of the primary factors is how often a particular property is in fact used by the code, you'll have to have some good examples of the properties you care about in the code base already, and they will need to be among the most commonly used members.

See [Visual Studio IntelliCode FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/faq) for more details about how to use this feature.